# ExpressionEngine edit_date formatting

Tags: edit-date, date-format

Is there a reason the edit_date in exp_channel_titles isn't in Unix time format?

I need to display the last edit date of a section of a website so I'm doing a simple query

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT title, edit_date FROM exp_channel_titles
                 INNER JOIN exp_structure using(entry_id)
                 WHERE (exp_structure.channel_id ='4' OR parent_id ='13') 
                 ORDER BY edit_date DESC LIMIT 1"}
       {edit_date format="%d%S %F %Y"}
{/exp:query}
```

However the edit date seems to be formatted in a non unix timestamp. Is there a specific reason for this?

/system/expressionengine/libraries/api/Api_channel_entries.php is set to

```
'edit_date' => $this->EE->localize->decode_date('%Y%m%d%H%i%s', $this->EE->localize->now, FALSE),
```

Should this be

```
'edit_date' => $this->EE->localize->decode_date('%U', $this->EE->localize->now, FALSE),
```

?

Using EE 2.5.5

[image]

**EDIT - reason for asking**

I ask because my outputs do not format correctly:

Eg; edit_Date of 20130111181835

```
Last Updated - {edit_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
```

outputs -

> Last Updated - October 30, 639867

I've since tried priting the edit date of a normal post and it still it not formatted correctly. I will go check my settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpressionEngine gives `edit_date` special treatment inside the Channel Entries loop to account for the way it's saved, but inside a query it's just another 14-digit number. To get it to format properly in a query loop, the SELECT statement can be modified to offset the value from GMT and convert it to a Unix timestamp. Luckily, EE's `current_time` variable parses early enough to use it as the offset value.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(edit_date,'+00:00','{current_time format="%P"}')) AS edit_date
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain if your question is answerable as is, at least from non-Ellis Lab developers. It inquires about a reason, rather than asking for guidance or a solution.

What I can say is the `edit_date` format has been in non-Unix time format from before ExpressionEngine 2.5.5. I checked three sites: one using 2.5.5, one using 2.5.3, and one using 1.7.2 all have the edit date stored the same way.

I can also say, this doesn't change the expected behavior of the `edit_date` [variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#edit-date) as indicated by the [ExpressionEngine User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/)

I tested with

```
{edit_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
```

and it returns

> November 29, 2012

So while I can't state the reason why they would store it in non-unix format, it does look like it was planned, since their date variables work appropriately for it.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response! have clarified reason for asking. My outputs for edit_date (inside queries or channel:entries) do not format as expected.

Comment: I guess there was something wrong with my install - I re-uploaded all files and all was well and good, edit_date format="" now works as expected. Thanks for the information above, it helped me realize this wasn't a bug.

Comment: No problem. Glad things worked.

Comment: Maybe I was too quick to comment - It seems {edit_date format=""} doesn't work inside a {exp:query sql=""}{/exp:query} tag pair - at least not in any versions of EE I have.